# C++ shortcut for ->operator[]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class, I override the [] operator and it works fine if I have the class instantiated inside the method. But if want to pass it as a pointer, I need to do this to call the operator:

```
function(MyData * myData){
    int myInt = myData->operator[](i);
}
```

This looks very ugly, I might just as well not use the operator and define a proper function.

I'm asking if there is a syntactic sugar, I'm a noob so I'm not sure, but I could probably make a copy constructor or something and copy the stuff on to the stack and use the operator properly, but that's slow, I'd rather access the memory directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
int myInt = (*myData)[i];
```

That's syntactically equivalent to

```
int myInt = myData->operator[](i);
```

If you pass the object by reference, it becomes easier still.

```
void function(MyData& myData){
    int myInt = myData[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities. Either write

```
void function( MyData * myData ){
    // ...
    int myInt = ( *myData )[i];
}
```

or introduce an intermediate reference

```
void function( MyData * myData ){
    // ...
    MyData &data = *myData;
    int myInt = data[i];
}
```